# Iam getting errors in the code

Tags: lightning-web-components

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';

import getAccountlist from '@salesforce/apex/AccountHelper.getAccountList';
export default class Lwc_to_apex_mode extends LightningElement {

    @wire{getAccountlist} Accounts;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take our [tour] and read [ask] and [help/on-topic], then make an [edit] to your post to describe the _specific problem_. We can't necessarily guess what error you are receiving, so please help the community help you.

Comment: In this case, you _definitely_ have a syntax error (look at that `@wire` carefully!) but please do edit your post so someone can construct a good answer for you.

Comment: May I know what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@wire{getAccountlist} Accounts;` should be `@wire(getAccountlist) Accounts;`. Also note that it traditional to have properties start with a lowercase letter, so it should more formally be: `@wire(getAccountlist) accounts;` Also, remember that JavaScript is case sensitive, so pay attention to your capitalization.

Comment: Thank you it worked for me